# PowerShell copy and rename multiple .csv files from 10+ subfolders

Tags: powershell, csv, merge, copy

I'm searching for a way to copy multiple .csv files all named exactly the same, located in different folders (all of them are in the same dierctory) and merge them into 1 .csv file (I would like to skip copying the first line which is head, except from the first file and there is no rule how many lines are written in each .csv file, so the script should recognize written lines to know how many and which one to merge /to avoid blank lines).

This is what I tried so far:

```
$src = "C:\Users\E\Desktop\Merge\Input\Files*.csv"
$dst = "C:\Users\E\Desktop\Merge\Output"

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse -File | Copy-Item -Destination $dst
```

and this one:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse -File | Copy-Item -Destination $dst | 
ForEach-Object {
$NewName = $_.Name
$Destination = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath $NewName
Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination -Force
}
```

any help please? :)

Comment: Do all these csv files have the same headers? If yes you could use [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1) in a loop to get all the contained data and output all data to one sinlge csv file with [Export-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1) using the parameter -Append.

Comment: Yes they all have the same headers. I'm currently struggling with: Get-Content : An object at the specific path does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to merge the files you may as well read them all into PowerShell, and then output the whole thing at once. You could do something like:

```
$Data = Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse -File | Import-Csv
$Data | Export-Csv $dst\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

That may not be feasible if your CSV files are extremely large, but it is a simple way to merge CSV files if the header row is the same in all files.

Another method would be to just treat it as text, which is much less memory intensive. For that you would want to get a list of files, copy the first one intact, and then copy the rest of them skipping the header row.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse
$TargetFile = Join-Path $dst $Files[0].Name
$Files[0] | Copy-Item -Dest $TargetFile
#Skip the first file, and loop through the rest
$Files | Select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{
    #Get the contents of the file, and skip the header row, then append the rest to the target
    Get-Content $_ | Select -Skip 1 | Add-Content $TargetFile
}
```

**Edit:** Ok, I wanted to replicate the process so that I could figure out what was giving you errors. To do that I created 3 folders, and copied a .csv file with 4 entries into each folder, with all of the files named 'Files 06202018.csv'. I ran my code above, and it did what it should, but there was some file corruption where the second file would be appended directly to the end of the first file without a new line being created for it, so I changed things from just copying the first file, to reading it and creating a new file in the destination. The below code worked flawlessly for me:

```
$src = "C:\Temp\Test\Files*.csv" 
$dst = "C:\Temp\Test\Output"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse 
$TargetFile = Join-Path $dst $Files[0].Name
GC $Files[0] | Set-Content $TargetFile 
#Skip the first file, and loop through the rest 
$Files | Select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{ 
    #Get the contents of the file, and skip the header row, then append the rest to the target 
    Get-Content $_ | Select -Skip 1 | Add-Content $TargetFile 
}
```

That took the files:

```
C:\Temp\Test\Lapis\Files 06202018.csv
C:\Temp\Test\Malachite\Files 06202018.csv
C:\Temp\Test\Opal\Files 06202018.csv
```

And it combined those three files into a correctly merged file at:

```
C:\Temp\Test\Output\Files 06202018.csv
```

The only time that I had any issues is if I forgot to delete the target file before running this. Depending on how large these files are, and how much memory you have available, you could probably speed this up by changing the last two lines to this:

```
    Get-Content $_ | Select -Skip 1
} | Add-Content $TargetFile
```

That would read all of the files in (other than the first one) and only write to the destination once, instead of having to get file lock, open the file for writing, write, and close the destination for each file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to merge like this: `$src = "C:\Users\E\Desktop\Merge\Input\Files*.csv"
$dst = "C:\Users\E\Desktop\Merge\Output"

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse -File | Copy-Item -Destination $dst

$Files = Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse
$TargetFile = Join-Path $dst $Files[0].Name
$Files[0] | Copy-Item -Dest $TargetFile
#Skip the first file, and loop through the rest
$Files | Select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{
    #Get the contents of the file, and skip the header row, then append the rest to the target
    Get-Content $_ | Select -Skip 1 | Add-Content $TargetFile
}`

Comment: I'm getting this error: Get-Content : An object at the specific path does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.

Comment: Take out the unneeded `Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse -File | Copy-Item -Destination $dst ` and do `Get-Content $_.FullName | Select -Skip 1 | Add-Content $TargetFile`

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I did as instructed and now I'm getting this error in powershell: Get-Content : An object at the specified path C:\Users\E\Desktop\Merge\Input\Lapus\Files.csv does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter. At C:\Users\E\Desktop\test6.ps1:12 char:5 + Get-Content $_ | Select -Skip 1 | Add-Content $TargetFile + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand –

Comment: If you just define `$src` and `$dst` before my second code block it should do what you want.

Comment: I tried with your second code block and I have defined $src and $dst and still no success with the same error as before. Do you think it might get confused as all  files are named excatly the same, only located in different subfolders?

Comment: Did you verify that a file exists at 'C:\Users\E\Desktop\Merge\Input\Lapus\Files.csv'? Is that file locked by another process?

Comment: Yes I did. There are 34 folders and in each folder there is a file named Files 62018.csv - that's why there is \Files*.csv in $src (there is different date created in file name each month eg. 62018, 72018..)

Comment: Hopefully this last edit helps clear up any remaining issues you're seeing.

Comment: It works! Thank you! The problem was on my side.. firstly with last code didn't work either. The thing is I had [NAME] in file name (eg. \Files [NAME] 62018.csv) and when I manually removed the "[NAME]" part it went through flawlessly. Any suggestions on how to bypass that or should I simply add a code to rename all files (remove [*] part) before trying to merge them?

Comment: Use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` and then reference `$Files[0].FullName` and `$_.FullName` instead of just `$Files[0]` and `$_`. Or were you having trouble with the `Get-ChildItem` command? Also, if this answer resolved your issue please mark it as accepted to assist future SO users with a similar problem.